# Constructing a specific iterative function

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, soft-question, uniform-distribution

I have a problem at hand that i would like to share with giving my inputs and hoping for some from this site. so here it goes.

I have a matrix say a $4\times 4$ matrix $$A= \begin{bmatrix}
a_{11}    &    a_{12}    &      a_{13}    &    a_{14}    \\
  a_{21}    & a_{22}    &a_{23}    &a_{24}    \\
a_{31}    &a_{32}    &a_{33}    &a_{34}    \\
a_{41}    &a_{42}    &a_{43}    &a_{44}    \\
\end{bmatrix}$$  each $a_{ij}\in \{0,1,2,3,4....N-1\}$
I have a fixed number $r\in\{0,1,2.....N-1\}$ I define the equations as 
$$ b_{1,1}    = r \oplus a_{11}   $$  and then the recurrence relation 
$$b_{i,j}   =  a_{i,j}    \oplus b_{i, j-1} ~~forall~ j\neq 1$$
$$b_{2,1}    =a_{2,1}    \oplus b_{1,4} ,b_{3,1}    =a_{3,1}    \oplus b_{2,4}, b_{4,1}    =a_{4,1}    \oplus b_{3,4}$$ these equations mean that the current value of $b_{i,j}$ depends on the current $a$ and previous $b$ that has just been calculated, here $\oplus $ means the bitwise XOR  between two operands. What this transformation does is it generates a matrix that has entries uniformly distributed between
 $ \{0,1,2,3,4....N-1\}$, and that it is easily reversible so that given $a$ and $b_{i,j}$ i can easily calculate each entry of matrix $A$.
My question is can we define a rule other this  that does the two aforementioned jobs but is not easily invertible in the sense that you cannot get $A$ easily.

Comment: I thought the "two jobs" were (1) uniform distribution of $b_{i,j}$ and (2) easy to calculate $A$ given $B$ and $r$.  So what do you mean you want a rule which does these two jobs BUT is not easy to calculate $A$ given $B$ and $r$?  Do you mean you want a new rule which does only job (1) but does the opposite of job (2)?

Comment: BTW, your existing rule does not generate a uniform $B$, unless $A$ itself is uniformly random to begin with.

Comment: yes you understood it correctly. How do i make such a rule if $A$ is uniform.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO it is better to look at this as encryption.

Just to be clearly, your requirement is to find a function $f(r,A) = B$ s.t. if an adversary is given $\{r, B\}$ they cannot (easily) calculate $A$.  This is exactly what [public-key encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) or [secure hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Hash_Algorithms) is about.

(You further want $B$ to look uniformly random but this will mostly follow from the first requirement, if you use encryption or even hashing.  The good ones all make the result look uniformly random - even if the input $A$ is actually not.)

A super brief primer: $r$ is the public key, and is known to everyone.  You encrypt a message $m$ with $r$, resulting in encrypted text $c = e(r, m)$.  To decrypt $c$ back to $m$, however, requires a *different* key called private key $q$, i.e. $m = d(q, c)$.  If the adversary doesn't have $q$, it should be hard to calculate $m$ (or $q$ for that matter) from $\{r, c\}$.  There are various well-known ways to construct the system $\{r, q, e(), d()\}$ and such systems have been in use for actual online encryption and authentication for decades.  Start with the wikipedia article above for more details.

So if you have such a system set up, all you need is $b_{ij} = e(r, a_{ij})$.  Optionally, you can daisy-chain e.g. $b_{ij} = e(r, a_{ij} \oplus b_{i,j-1})$ etc, but I'm not sure this is actually more secure.  (Security is a question of which system is (slightly?) easier to hack/break... but I am not a security expert.)  Well at least, if you don't daisy-chain, then identical entries in $A$ will encrypt to identical entries in $B$, so if that's a concern, then you should daisy-chain.

If you find the public-key systems difficult to implement, then maybe you can use some kind of [secure hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Hash_Algorithms).  A secure hash is something that, by definition, is hard to reverse.  Think of it as like public-key but there is only an encryption (public) key but no decryption (private) key.  If you have such a $hash()$ function (and these are really widely available), then something like $b_{ij} = hash(r \oplus a_{ij})$ or perhaps $b_{ij} = hash(concatenate(r,a_{ij}))$ should work pretty well.  You can daisy chain them too.